# Integrating Custom PHP-CodeSniffer Rules to Eclipse

Tags: php

I have created custom php_codesniffer rule which i want to integrate in the Eclipse. I have added new rule in Eclipse->prefrences->phptool->PHPCodesniffer. Also enables php_Codesniffer validation.But when I am going to apply it,it gives me error

**'Unable to execute File - Reason-Launch configuration at file c:/user/abc/workspace/.metadata/.plugin/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/pti_phpcs doesn't exist.'**

And rule doesn't get applied. But when I am going to apply the default rule PEAR,Sniff it get applied without any error.

Can anybody tell me ,Is there anything need to check/set or I am doing something wrong. I need to Add custom PHP-CodeSniffer rule in Eclipse for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive about eclipse, but to get in going in Netbeans, I had to create a directory in my CodeSniffer Standards directory for my custom rules

/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/CUSTOM

and then put the ruleset.xml file in the CUSTOM directory.

Komodo allows you to designate the ruleset with --standard directive, but that does not work in Netbeans and possibly not in eclipse either

Comment: Finally i found the way to import custom codesniffer  rule in to eclipse. 
First open preferneces->phpcodesniffer.
Check for pear library path by clicking on pear library link. If path is not mentioned in the list then create new path and mentioned the  pear installed path. then apply it and come back to phptool-phpcodesniffer page,select the pear path installed library,then you can see all the custom rules in the list.then select one of them and apply.
It works for me.

Comment: glad you got it going! CodeSniffer implementation (highlighting) is one of the reasons I prefer Netbeans to Komodo. I'll have to check it out in eclipse

Comment: @Gaurav, please place your comment as the solution to this problem, because it is "the solution". It's just hard to find when it is posted in the comments of someone else's post, which is a post that is not even the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had several problem trying to install CodeSniffer and make it run with Eclipse properly.

That was the steps I followed to made it run properly, you will find on this post detailed instructions about how to configure, [How to Eclipse + CodeSniffer + CakePHP Sniff](http://blog.zot24.com/how-to-codesniffer-cakephp-code-with-eclipse/).

---

Go to the preferences menu on `Eclipse` and navigate to...

```
PHP -> PHP Executables -> Add...
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [zot24.com](http://blog.zot24.com/content/images/2014/Feb/configuring_php_homebrew_in_eclipse.png))</sub>

Once we have PHP configured on our Eclipse we have to setup `PEAR` go to...

```
PHP Tools -> Library -> PEAR -> New...
```

And select the `path` where `php55` was installed using `homebrew`, you can run this command to know the path of `php55`

```
brew --prefix php55
```

Then just add at the end of that command

```
.../lib/PHP
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [zot24.com](http://blog.zot24.com/content/images/2014/Feb/codesniffer_cakephp_eclipse_1.png))</sub>

And the last step is select our just configured `PEAR` path a the default library used by our `PHP CodeSniffer`, as you can see on the imagen below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [zot24.com](http://blog.zot24.com/content/images/2014/Feb/codesniffer_cakephp_eclipse_2.png))</sub>

And done! just enjoy a code clean! :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [zot24.com](http://blog.zot24.com/content/images/2014/Feb/codesniffer_cakephp_eclipse_3.png))</sub>